# Gregorian timestamp - how to convert this to readable format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timestamp

I'm currently building a React application for a take home assignment for a job interview and I'm currently stuck on a timestamp that I have not seen before.

```
  {
    "type": "motion",
    "startTime": "637703442050000000",
    "duration": 2000,
    "eventId": "d2faf37d-6fb4-40b3-996c-1703044c724e"
  },
```

I've search the web last night for hours to be led on different paths but I'm still stumped on this. Any kind soul of there that can shed some light on the startTime entry. I need to convert this timestamp so that I can do some calculations on event lengths.

Edit: it's an 18 digit number for clarity

Thanks :)

Apologies - just read some more information that I did not see

Dates/times are expressed in ticks, that is: the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar. For example: 637703442050000000 is equal to 2021-10-20 16:30:05. Durations are in milliseconds.

Comment: that is a BIG number!! dividing it by 1000000 gives a date of Match 18 1990 ...

Comment: It might be an Epoch timestamp in *nanoseconds* (nanoseconds since Jan 1 1970 at midnight UTC), in which case it would be `1990-03-17T19:50:42.070Z` (`new Date(637703442070000000 / 1000000)`). But you'll need to find out from whatever API you're getting that value from, some systems start at Jan 1 1900 or other reference dates.

Comment: Is there any indication AT ALL what that may be referring to?

Comment: I got `2021-10-20T16:30:07.000Z` ... but I see you changed the number

Comment: @Jaromanda I changed it to match the information I received on the document, that number that you reached sounds correct ! :)  -  how did you reach this btw, still stumped :(